# Make one div display below another

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a fixed div element at the top of the page. It can have varying height depends on word count. Underneath is a scrollable list. I would like the list to always appear a small distance below the fixed div element. So the margin top will be 10px. The set up is as follows:

```
<div fixed>
  fixed item here
</div>

<div>
  scrolling item here
</div>
```

Comment: Put both of those elements inside a new element, and make that the only element with `position: fixed`. Problem solved.

Comment: That's not possible because `display: fixed` is removed from the normal workflow ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)). So the second `div` doesn't "know" it's there. The only way I can think of is using Javascript to determine the height of the fixed div after it's loaded and add that to the position of the second div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ion-header and ion-content to achieve this. Put the fixed header div in ion-header and the scrolling list inside ion-content.

P.S. you can even put ion-header and ion-content inside another ion-content if needed.